# Spring MVC, Rest and Shiro. @RequiresAuthentication not works

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, shiro

I use Spring 4.1.2, Shiro 1.2.3 (core, web, spring) and I am creating RestControllers. In class like in example I use @RequiresAuthentication annotation to prevent accessing method.

```
@RestController
@RequestMapping("/api")
public class CarController {

    @RequestMapping("/secure")
    @RequiresAuthentication
    public String secure() {
        Subject subject = SecurityUtils.getSubject();
        return "Should be 'true' == " + subject.isAuthenticated();
    }


    @RequestMapping("/insecure")
    public String insecure() {
        Subject subject = SecurityUtils.getSubject();
        return "Should be 'false' == " + subject.isAuthenticated();
    }
}
```

Unfortunately I can access both of the methods. Also both of them return `false` as a result of `subject.isAuthenticated()`. What am I missing?

Answer (score 4):

I found an answer. I had to add to my Java Spring Configuration following code:

```
// enable shiro annotations
@DependsOn("lifecycleBeanPostProcessor")
@Bean
public DefaultAdvisorAutoProxyCreator defaultAdvisorAutoProxyCreator() {
    DefaultAdvisorAutoProxyCreator proxyCreator = new DefaultAdvisorAutoProxyCreator();
    proxyCreator.setProxyTargetClass(true);
    return proxyCreator;
}

// enable shiro annotations
@Bean
public AuthorizationAttributeSourceAdvisor authorizationAttributeSourceAdvisor() {
    AuthorizationAttributeSourceAdvisor advisor = new AuthorizationAttributeSourceAdvisor();
    advisor.setSecurityManager(securityManager);
    return advisor;
}
```